What's the relationship between the sections of $\mathcal O(1)$ and $T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m$?
I was reading Vincent Bouchard notes. On section $3.3.1$, I face some issue:

First, we need to compute the total Chern class of $\mathbb{C P}^m$. We recall that homogeneous coordinates $z_i, i=0, \ldots, m$ of $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ are sections of the hyperplane line bundle $L$. Thus, the holomorphic tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ is spanned by tangent vectors $s_i(z) \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$, where the $s_i$ are any sections of $L$. Now, on $\mathbb{C P}^m$, the holomorphic tangent bundle $T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m$ is also spanned by $s_i(z) \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$, with the $s_i$ any sections of the hyperplane line bundle - which we now denote by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P} m}(1)$.

Question 1: I didn't understand why $T^{1,0}\mathbb{CP}^m$ is spanned by $s_i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$ where $s_i$ are sections of hyperplane bundle? And does it satisfy locally or globally? because we can construct a global section for $\mathcal O(1)$, let’s start with a partial section on $U_0$, i.e. an element in $k[Z_1/Z_0]$. Now, to transition this function from $U_0$ to $U_1$ all we are allowed to do is multiply it by $\frac{Z_0}{Z_1}$ and it lands in $k[Z_0/Z_1]$. And for the tangent bundle I recall a example from the Griffiths page-409, where we have $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}\setminus\{0\}\stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{CP}^m$
\begin{align*}
     \pi_*\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_i} \right) &= \begin{cases}
         \frac{1}{Z_0}\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}, &i=1,\cdots,n\\
         -\sum_i\frac{Z_i}{Z_0^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i},&i=0
     \end{cases}
\end{align*}
In general, I couldn't relate their sections intuitively.

But we have to take equivalence classes with respect to overall rescaling, since overall rescaling is trivial in $\mathbb{C P}^m$. That is, we have a map from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(1)^{\oplus(m+1)}$ to $T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m$ such that its kernel is the trivial line bundle $\mathbb{C}$ of multiples of a nowhere-vanishing generator $\left(z_0, \ldots, z_m\right) \mapsto z_i \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} \cong 0$ in $\mathbb{C P}^m$.

Question 2: Let $f:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(1)^{\oplus(m+1)}\rightarrow T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m$ then $\operatorname{Ker}f=\{s_i(z):s_i(z)=z_i\}\subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(1)^{\oplus(m+1)}$. I didn't see how $\operatorname{Ker}f$ is trivial line bundle ($\mathbb{CP}^m\times\mathbb C$) over $\mathbb{CP}^m$?
It will be a great help if anyone could shed some light.

These posts of mine might help a little: here, here.

tl; dr: $\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Ocal}{\mathcal{O}}$To me it's natural geometrically to include the tautological bundle $\tau := \Ocal(-1)$ into the trivial rank-$(m+1)$ bundle $\Cpx^{m+1}$, and then to identify the quotient $Q = \Cpx^{m+1}/\tau$ in terms of the tangent bundle. It turns out $Q \simeq \Ocal(-1) \otimes T\Proj^{m}$.

For general reasons, $T\Proj^{m}$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(\tau, Q)$: Intuitively, if $p$ is a point of $\Proj^{m}$, then in the manifold $\Cpx^{m+1}\setminus\{0\}$ that projects to $\Proj^{m}$,

$p$ is represented by the tautological fiber $\tau_{p}$, and
a tangent vector in $T_{p}\Proj^{m}$ is a mapping of the line $\tau_{p}$ into "directions in $\Cpx_{p}^{m+1}$ linearly independent from $\tau_{p}$," i.e., the fiber $\Cpx_{p}^{m+1}/\tau_{p}$.

(Using a metric, we can represent the quotient $\Cpx_{p}^{m+1}/\tau_{p}$ by the orthogonal complement $\tau_{p}^{\perp}$ in $\Cpx_{p}^{m+1}$, but orthogonal complements do not vary holomorphically with $p$. The quotient, by contrast, does vary holomorphically. The cost is, there is no natural inclusion of the quotient into $\Cpx_{p}^{m+1}$, see also here. If memory serves, Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris has more detailed discussion as needed.)
We therefore have a short exact sequence of vector bundles over $\Proj^{m}$:
$$
0 \to \tau \to \Cpx^{m+1} \to Q \to 0.
$$
Tensoring with the hyperplane bundle $\Ocal(1)$, which is dual to $\tau$, gives
$$
0 \to \Cpx \to \Ocal(1)^{m+1} \to \Ocal(1) \otimes Q \to 0.
$$
Finally, $\Ocal(1) \otimes Q \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(\tau, Q) \simeq T\Proj^{m}$. Substituting gives Bouchard's description in the form of a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \Cpx \to \Ocal(1)^{m+1} \to T\Proj^{m} \to 0.
$$
(Edited to Add) Suppose $V$ is a vector space, $\ell$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $V$, and $p$ is a non-zero vector in $\ell$, i.e., a projective representative of $\ell = [p]$ viewed as an element of $\Proj(V)$. For each $v$ in $V$, the path $\gamma(t) = p + tv$ represents a tangent vector to $\Proj(V)$ at $[p]$. Viewing $v$ as an element of $V/\ell$ defines a linear surjection $V \to T_{[p]}\Proj(V)$ whose kernel is $\ell$. Geometrically, the projective image of $\gamma$ is constant if $v \in \ell$, so the kernel contains $\ell$; inversely we lose one dimension, so the kernel is precisely $\ell$.
Assembling this coordinate-invariant pointwise description as $[p]$ ranges over $\Proj^{m}$, a section of the tangent bundle $T\Proj^{m}$ (conceptually, a holomorphic choice of $v$ as a function of $p$) is a mapping from the tautological bundle $\tau$ to the quotient $Q := \Cpx^{m+1}/\tau$.
(Generally, and for similar reasons, if $W$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of a complex vector space $V$, then the tangent space to the Grassmannian $G^{k}(V)$ at $W$ may be invariantly identified with $\operatorname{Hom}(W, V/W)$.)

Actually, I didn't read too much material on Complex geometry. As I am working on a problem which led me to read all of these material by own. It still hard to gasp $\mathbb{C}^{m+1} / \mathcal{O}(-1) \simeq \mathcal{O}(-1) \otimes T \mathbb{C P}^m$. If I quotient out $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ by $\mathcal{O}(-1)=\left{([x], \ell) \in \mathbb{C P}^m \times \mathbb{C}^{m+1} \mid x \in \ell\right}$ then what we will get? continue...[1]

And I interpret the right side as, Each point on $\mathbb{CP}^m$ correspond to a line from $\mathcal O(-1)$, and the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{CP}^m$ which represent the direction where we can move from that point. So, I failed to connect them. Like how to mentally visualize left/right side? If possible I want to see an action of a tangent vector (like for small space $\mathbb{C P}^1$ ) to understand, "... mapping of the line $\tau_p$ into "directions in $\mathbb{C}_p^{m+1}$ linearly independent from $\tau_p$ ". continue...[2]

Because all of these seem new to me and without understanding that I guess I couldn't understand your beautiful answer (+1) @AndrewD.Hwang

Thanks for your effort, @AndrewD.Hwang. I guess I manage to understand $T\mathbb{CP}^m$. but still want to verify something. Isn't modding out $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ by the fibers of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$take the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ and collapsing all the vectors that belong to the same line to a single point? And give $Q\simeq \mathbb{CP}^m$? Then $\operatorname{Hom}(\tau, Q)$ become $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O(-1), \mathbb{CP}^n)$ and does it consist of linear maps that take each fiber of $\mathcal O(-1)$ to the corresponding point in $\mathbb{CP}^n$?

My apology for misleading notation: Throughout, $\mathbf{C}^{m+1}$ stands for the trivial rank-$(m+1)$ vector bundle over projective space (not for the affine space whose line subspaces comprise projective space). The tautological bundle $\tau$ is a line subbundle, and the quotient is a vector bundle of rank $m$ over projective space.
